# Sending client certificate without installing its CA into the certificate store

Tags: .net, ssl, client-certificates

Is there a way to use a client certificate without installing its CA into the certificate store?  There is exactly one client certificate (as a pfx file) added to HttpWebRequest.ClientCertificates, and that single one should be used even if the corresponding CA certificate is not available in the certificate store.

```
HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("https://server/");
X509Certificate2 cert = X509Certificate2("cert.p12", "secret");
req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
```

Enabling detailed socket logging gives me this:

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [15136] SecureChannel#46104728 - We have user-provided certificates. The server has specified 8 issuer(s). Looking for certificates that match any of the issuers.
System.Net Information: 0 : [15136] SecureChannel#46104728 - Left with 0 client certificates to choose from.
```

The client doesn't find any suitable client certificate since it doesn't recognize the CA that has signed it.  I don't care, I want to use it anyway.  Can this be achieved?

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't create your own CA and add its certificate/key to your server (since you would have to reconfigure the server to accept your random client certificates anyway)?

Comment: I do have my own CA, and it's installed on the server.  The problem is on the client.
The server reports 8 possible issuers.  One of them is the CA that has signed the client certificate.  The client just doesn't know about it, because the CA is not in any certificate store on the client machine.  And it can not be installed on the client machine because of policy restrictions.

Comment: Are you able to install your CA certificate to the store on a test client to verify that is the problem?  I'm wondering if the problem could instead be that your pfx file omits the full chain of certificates through the CA.  If you are correct that it is a store issue, one thing that might work is to spoof the Distinguished Name of a certificate that is already trusted on the machine with a new CA that you create, because the CertificateRequest message sent from the server only contains DNs and not full certificates.

Comment: You could also try using `HttpWebRequest.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` in case validation for client certificate CAs comes through there, but I'm guessing it doesn't.

Comment: Answer to rhashimoto: Yes, I have verified that this is the problem.  If the CA that has signed the client certificate is installed in the certificate store, the client certificate is successfully sent to the server.
I have tried to create the pfx in different ways, both containing only the client certificate with private key, and as well containing also the whole CA chain.  It did not make any difference.
I haven't tried the spoofing approach, but even if only DNs are sent, the client would probably try to verify the client cert for each one of them?

Comment: I have already implemented a ServerCertificateValidationCallback.  It has impact on the server certificate validation, but not on the client certificate.

Comment: You're right that there's no guarantee that spoofing a DN would work but it's at least possible that the way the library works is to check the DN against the trust store and then match the DN on the client certificate list.  I can't think of any other approach short of using a different HTTPS library.

Comment: Moving to another library was the solution.  This works fine now when using libcurl instead.  However, I'm still curious if this could have worked with out-of-the-box .NET has well.

Comment: Years later I find your question and wondering how it was solved?  We are being forced to use a client cert, but I do not want to install the Intermediate Certs cos I don't trust them enough to install them into the Store (but I am forced to trust them for one particular TLS interaction).